# free sql code editor?

Tags: sql

i am breaking my eyes trying to write sql code in ms access. is there a free editor out there?

Comment: You should probably switch to SQL Server.

Comment: Its a pretty good question to be asked as people searching in google for editor will get to this result.

Comment: Is your database an Access File or are you using Access as client interface to another type of database file or server?

Comment: Oh, yes, switching to SQL Server is always the magical solution to everything. It got rid of my hemorrhoids!

Comment: @David-W-Fenton congrads! i hope they are still gone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express**

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en

**MS SQL Code Factory**

http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mssql/codefactory/

**DatabaseSpy SQL Editor**

http://www.altova.com/databasespy/sql-editor.html

**SQuirrel SQL Client**

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en)

You should be able to use it as a SQL editor without SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use [SQuirrel SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots) to connect to just about any database I need to work with.  You can use it with any database you can find a JDBC driver for.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but I believe they improved the editor in Access 2010 .  Here's a post from the Access Blog that [discuss IntelliSense](http://blogs.msdn.com/access/archive/2009/08/11/write-expressions-faster-with-less-errors.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) mentioned and of course you get the syntax highlighting but not any intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote Access SQL Editor, an Add-In for Microsoft Access, because I had the same problem.  There is a free 14-day trial [here](https://www.fieldeffect.info/trial/).   [Purchasing](https://www.fieldeffect.info/purchase/) a license is very cheap, but if you can't afford it, you can [contact me](http://fieldeffect.info/wp/access-sql-editor-documentation/).

Once it's installed, you can access it through your Add-Ins menu (In Access 2010 it's Database Tools->Add Ins).